# How can I remove whitespace in HTML?

Tags: html, whitespace

I would like to be able to go from this:

```
<label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Phone number</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" aria-describedby="phoneHelp">
<div id="phoneHelp" class="form-text">This is in case of quick questions.</div>
```

to this (very long line intentional):

```
<label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Phone number</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" aria-describedby="phoneHelp"><div id="phoneHelp" class="form-text">This is in case of quick questions.</div>
```

In other words, delete indenting and collapsed whitespace between tags in a selection in an HTML buffer. The general goal is making the file more legible, as the collapsed portions typically are repeated form elements that differ only for a small detail.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```lisp
(defun collapse ()
    (interactive)
    (replace-regexp "> *[\n]+ *<" "><"))
```

### Edited:

Just on selection:

```lisp
(defun collapse ()
  (interactive (if (use-region-p)
                   (progn
                     (setq start (region-beginning))
                     (setq end (region-end))
                     (goto-char start)
                     (while
                         (re-search-forward "> *[\n]+ *<" end t)
                       (replace-match "><" nil nil))))))
```

Comment: Hmm... almost. It looks like it does that in the whole buffer, not just on the selection.

Answer (score 0):

Why not run `tidy`?

Mark the region and `M-:` this

```lisp
(apply #'call-process-region (region-beginning) (region-end)
       "tidy"
       t '(t . nil) t
       '("--vertical-space" "auto"
         "--wrap" "0"
         "--show-warnings" "no"
         "--show-info" "no"
         "-q"))
```

Adjust the `tidy`'s command line parameters depending on your needs.